# Creating _MouseLeftButtonDown for dynamically created rectangles in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, rectangles

My application shows the **layout of an office floor** where the seats are depicted as a rectangle and the margins, strokes, height, width and alignment are saved in the database for each Seat ID. Based on the allocation status, the fill of the rectangle is either red or green. Allocation status and the occupancy details are saved in the SQL db. I need to have separate **MouseLeftButtonDown** method for each rectangles. which will show me the occupant details.

```
//Code Behind
public SeatUserControl()
        {
         string cubeId = "";
         string status = "";
         string name = "";
         string number = "";
         int height = 0;
         int width = 0;
         int leftMargin = 0;
         int topMargin = 0;
            InitializeComponent(); 
            SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string SqlQuery = "select c.SeatId,c.Height,c.Width,c.Stroke,c.MarginTop,c.MarginLeft,e.Status,e.EmpName,e.EmpNumber from SeatDetails c Join MasterData e ON c.SeatId =e.SeatId";
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            sqlconn.Open();
            data = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, sqlconn);
            data.Fill(dt);
            try
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    leftMargin = int.Parse(row["MarginLeft"].ToString());
                    topMargin = int.Parse(row["MarginTop"].ToString());
                    height = int.Parse(row["Height"].ToString());
                    width = int.Parse(row["width"].ToString());
                    status = row["Status"].ToString();
                    cubeId = row["SeatId"].ToString();
                    name = row["EmpName"].ToString();
                    number = row["EmpNumber"].ToString();
                    PlaceRectangles();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
        public string PlaceRectangles()
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.Height = height;
            rect.Width = width;
            SolidColorBrush StrokeBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            rect.Stroke = StrokeBrush;
            rect.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            rect.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            rect.Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin, topMargin, 0, 0);
            rect.RadiusX = 8;
            rect.RadiusY = 5;
           if (status.Equals("Allocated"))
            {
                SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.RoyalBlue);
                rect.Fill = myBrush;
            }
           else if (status.Equals("Available"))
            {
                SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                rect.Fill = myBrush;
            }
           else 
            {
                SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                rect.Fill = myBrush;
            }
            seatCanvas.Children.Add(rect);
     }
}

//XAML
<UserControl x:Class="SpaceAllocator.SeatUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="580" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Height="580" Width="800">
        <Canvas Name="seatCanvas" Height="580" Width="800" Margin="0,3,-2,78">       </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
enter code here
```

Comment: It is highly recommendable that you use proper DataBinding and a proper ItemsControl and proper DataTemplates instead of creating and manipulating UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That approach is discouraged due to being problematic due to the complexities of the Visual Tree, and cumbersome due to it's procedural nature which in general requires more code and is less elegant than a declarative, DataBinding-based approach. Post your current code and XAML and I can tell you the proper way to do what you need in WPF.

Comment: Hi, @HighCore I have included the code behind and the XAML used in my application. Kindly suggest a better way.

Comment: @HighCore, can we do it any better way?

Comment: I'll prepare a small sample for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a rectangle add an event handler:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle rect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
rect.MouseLeftButtonDown += rect_MouseLeftButtonDown;
// apply margins and what not
```

Then you handle your mouse left button down here:

```
void rect_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
      var rect = sender as System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle;
      // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you call this code at startup of your application, an event handler is added automatically to all new objects of type Rectangle:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Rectangle), MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, 
    new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseDown), false);

private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Hi @Flat I am getting the below error:-
**"Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget"**.
It seems to me that classHandler is registered for first rectangle genarated and in the second loop it throws this exception.
My requirement here is to get as many handlers as the number of rectangles (based on the data in DB). Kindly suggest.

Comment: The function 'RegisterClassHandler' adds this handler to all Rectangles and not only the first. The error you are getting normaly occurs when you try to add one control to multiple parent elements, for example if you call 'seatCanvas.Children.Add(rect);' multiple times for the same object.

Comment: I got the problem now. It now works perfectly. @Flat